# count the number of rows in sql query result using access vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to  count the number of rows in sql query result using access 2007 vba. 
What I have is a text box named `AGN` when a user put value on it check for this value then it bring back `MsgBox` if the the value is already inserted.   What I try to do is :

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Dim db As Database
  Dim strSQL As String

  Set db = CurrentDb

 strSQL = "SELECT agencies.[agency no] FROM agencies WHERE agencies.[agency no]= " &Me.AGN.Text

  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.Fields.Count > 1 Then


MsgBox "this value is already here "

  End If

   Set rs = Nothing
```

When I insert any value on the textbox I got run time error 3061 (too few parameters)

Comment: [agency no] column is number type and the task that i want it  is to check if there is any rows returned by the query

Answer (score 3):

The *"too few parameters"* error message generally means there is something in your SQL statement which Access doesn't recognize as a field, table, function or SQL keyword.  In this case, it could happen if `[agency no]` is text rather than numeric data type.  If that is the case, enclose the value of `AGN` with quotes when you build the SQL statement. (Or you could use a parameter query to avoid the need to quote the text value.)

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT a.[agency no] FROM agencies AS a" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE a.[agency no]= '" & Me.AGN.Value & "'"
Debug.Print strSQL
```

In case of trouble, go to the Immediate window and copy the output from `Debug.Print`.  Then you can create a new query in the Access query designer, switch to SQL View and paste in the statement text for testing.

Once your `SELECT` is working, you can check whether or not the recordset is empty.  When it is empty both its `BOF` and `EOF` properties are true.  So to detect when it is *not* empty, check for `Not (BOF And EOF)` ...

```vb
With rs
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        MsgBox "this value is already here "
    End If
End With
```

However you don't actually need to open a recordset to determine whether a matching row exists.  You can check the value returned by a `DCount` expression.

```vb
Dim lngRows As Long
lngRows = DCount("*", "agencies", "[agency no]='" & Me.AGN.Value & "'")
If lngRows > 0 Then
    MsgBox "this value is already here "
End If
```

Notes:

1. I used `AGN.Value` instead of `AGN.Text` because the `.Text` property is only accessible when the control has focus.  But I don't know where you're using that checking code, so unsure which is the proper choice for you.
2. Notice the similarities between the `SELECT` query and the `DCount` options.  It's often easy to translate between the two.